# TextView inside EditText align

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Some days ago i was searching for an edittext implementation with a "label" inside for username input.
I found the following xml code from Stackoverflow.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username_editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:hint="Πατήστε εδώ"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLength="20"
            android:paddingLeft="125dp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >

             <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="12dp"
            android:text="Όνομα χρήστη:"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

The result was what i needed,except one thing.Both edittext and textview were not align in their y axis,the bottom of the text was not aligned in small resolutions.The screenshot i got from a 3.7 inches:
[image]

I draw a red line as you can see they are not align. Any help?

Comment: I know it won't look exactly the same, but are you aware of the `android:hint` attribute? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint

Comment: Yes i know it,i am using it already.TY btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align text, you need a Relativelayout with the layout parameter: **android:layout_alignBaseline** for your component. 
Try this and keep me updating:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username_editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:hint="Πατήστε εδώ"
        android:paddingLeft="125dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/username_editText"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/username_editText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Όνομα χρήστη:"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ok,i will try it out as soon as i can and i will inform you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

from your TextView. That line makes the TextView centered on the vertical axis whereas the EditText isn't. That's what causes the misalignment issue.